Create Alert when color changing - Indicator TradingView
I'd like to create an alert when the line of the Accummulation/Distribution indicator changes from Green to Red and Red to Green.
This is the code :
study("Accumulation/Distribution - with markers")

//AD  the Accumulation/Distribution cumulative running total line.

ad  = cum(  (((close - low) - (high - close)) / (high - low)) * volume )

ad1 = sma( ad , 9)
ad2 = sma( ad , 15)
adCross = cross(ad1, ad2) ? ad2 : na
adSmaller = ad1 < ad2
adLowHighColor = adSmaller? red : green
adDiff = ad1 - ad2
adMarker = adSmaller == true and adSmaller[1] == false ? adDiff : na

//plot(ad , color = green)
plot(adDiff, color=adLowHighColor, style=line, linewidth=2)
plot(adDiff, color=silver, style=area, transp=70)
plot(adMarker, color=maroon, linewidth=4, style=circles)

//plot(ad1, color=red)
//plot(ad2, color=blue)
//plot(adCross, color=green, linewidth=4, style=circles)

Thank you for your help !
I've tried to change with variables, but it's not working and my code skills are bad ...

I would humbly suggest you spend more time with coding because you are missing the basics. The color change is not an event in itself, it is a reaction to a change. You do not track a "color change" but you track the underlying change that triggers the color change. Discussing a "ternary operator" will probably not be a much of a help to you right now.
